# Передать класс как параметр в метод и создать в нём экзепляр класса.

Tags: java, javafx

Есть несколько таблиц в БД и несколько TableView, созданы классы-модели.
TableView заполняется следующим методом:

```
public void fillBidTable(ResultSet resultSet, TableView tableView) 
            throws SQLException {

    ObservableList<BidMdl> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     while (resultSet.next()) {
        ArrayList<String> cells = new ArrayList<>();
         for (int i = 1; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
             //Iterate Column
             if (isDate(resultSet.getString(i))) {
                 //if it's date then convert to dd.MM.YYYY
                 cells.add(convertDateForTable(resultSet.getString(i)));
             } else cells.add(resultSet.getString(i));
         }

         data.add(new BidMdl(cells));
     }
    tableView.setItems(data);

}
```

BidMdl - модель таблицы. Создавать такой метод для каждой таблицы не хочется, т.к. меняются две строки (BidMdl меняется на другую модель)

```
ObservableList<BidMdl> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

и

```
data.add(new BidMdl(cells));
```

Подскажите как передать и использовать BidMdl? Или, возможно, совсем изменить схему???
PS использовать switch я догадался, но мне не нравится такая портянка...

Comment: Про интерфейсы что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: Слышал, получается та же портянка только с интерфейсом))) Или я не понял, как правильно его использовать. Опыта ещё мало((

Comment: Используя интерфейс я всё равно напишу столько реализаций (представлений) этого интерфеса сколько у меня таблиц. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Вы можете описать в абстрактном классе или интерфейсе общие методы вашей модели. При реализации модели для конкретной таблицы вам потребуется переопределить и реализовать специфичные только для данной таблицы методы.  Используя интерфейсы вы можете написать универсальный код для обработки различных типов таблиц один раз, передавая ему в качестве параметра (или ещё как-нибудь) класс-конкретную реализацию модели нужной таблицы. Изучайте ООП.

Comment: ООП изучаю, используя интерфейсы написал общий код для моделей и получается так, что в этом конкретном методе он (код) и отличается. Вы пишете: "передавая ему в качестве параметра (или ещё как-нибудь) класс-конкретную реализацию модели нужной таблицы" Собственно в этом вопрос и был. В любом случае, благодарю за уделённое время.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам, вдруг кому понадобится) Создаём интерфейс от которого наследуем все модели таблиц.

```
public interface Models {}
```

Т.е. тот-же BidMdl объявляем

```
public class BidMdl implements Models{.........}
```

И наш метод приобретает следующий вид:

```
    public void fillTable(ResultSet resultSet, TableView tableView, Class mdlClass) throws SQLException {

    ObservableList<Models> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        ArrayList<String> cells = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            //Iterate Column
            if (isDate(resultSet.getString(i))) {
                //if it's date then convert to dd.MM.YYYY
                cells.add(convertDateForTable(resultSet.getString(i)));
            } else cells.add(resultSet.getString(i));
        }

        try {
            Models mdl = (Models) mdlClass.getDeclaredConstructor(ArrayList.class).newInstance(cells);
            data.add(mdl);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    tableView.setItems(data);

}
```

К передаваемым в метод параметрам добавил класс модели `Class mdlClass` и изменились интересующие меня строки)))

```
ObservableList<Models> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

теперь ObservableList состоит из объектов класса(интерфейса) от которого унаследованы все модели таблиц.

```
Models mdl = (Models) mdlClass.getDeclaredConstructor(ArrayList.class).newInstance(cells);
data.add(mdl);
```

А здесь мы создаём экземпляр класса вызывая объявленный конструктор класса и передаём ему параметры. После чего, добавляем в `data`